# How to get Azure Active Directory application's password with Powershell 7?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-7.0

I need to migrate to version 7 a PowerShell script that was used to create an Azure AD application with a custom password using [`New-AzADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-6.6.0)
cmdlet. However, with PowerShell version 7, [`New-AzADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-7.1.0) [no longer supports custom passwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azps-msgraph-migration-changes?view=azps-7.1.0). I've tried retrieving the automatically generated password from the output of this cmdlet but the credentials field in it is always empty. Is there a way to retrieve the password with any cmdlet in the Az.Resources module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post creating the app registration you **cannot** retrieve the value of created Client Secret in any way.

**As shown in the below image:**

[image]

You can refer this for more information about [secretText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordcredential?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).